# error timezone symfony en mac

Tags: php, symfony2

quiero aprender symfony framework.
Use los comandos de la documentacion para instalarlo en mi mac y se instalo correctamente la version 2.8.28.

Pero cuando quiero correr el servidor me sale este error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system'
  s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or
   the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me
  thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th
  e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s
  et date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

Tengo apache instalado con mamp y php5, configure la zona horaria como "America/Santiago" en los php.ini de todas las versiones que trae mamp y el error sigue apareciendo.

como se puede solucionar?

Comment: ¿Has reiniciado el servidor apache tras realizar los cambios?

Comment: reinicio mamp cada vez

Comment: debes verificar si de verdad cambiastes el php.ini correcto!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu instalación de PHP no tiene definida una zona horaria por defecto puedes asignar la zona horaria en el php.ini cambiando asignando el valor que de una zona horaria a:

```
date.timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

agregar en el .htaccess o en el virtualHost de apache:

```
php_value date.timezone 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

otra opción es en el inicio de tu código usar la función:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

**'America/Los_Angeles'** Es un ejemplo de una zona horaria puedes ver la lista en:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php